# J Meter Web Driver Sampler does not navigate to the url Specified

Tags: jmeter-plugins

Can someone please help me on the problem below:
I have added a ThreadGroup and Firefox driver config and Web Driver Sampler.
I have just written the below code in Web Driver Sampler:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

When I save this and run, the Firefox browser is getting launched, but it is not navigating to 'http://google.com'.

Can anyone please let me know why this is happening. I have tried this in 2 versions of Firefox, with the same result.

Comment: Do the log files for JMeter give you any clue? The first thing I would check for is an incorrect configuration.

Comment: Can you tell the JMeter, Firefox and the WebDriver plugin version you are using? As I used the same thing with FF 39, Plugin 1.3 and JMeter 2.12, after this your scenario is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the latest version of JMeter, Firefox and Webdriver plugin.

- WebDriver Sampler plugin 1.3.0 supports Firefox 39
- WebDriver Sampler plugin 1.2.1 supports Firefox 33
- WebDriver Sampler plugin 1.2.0 supports Firefox 26

Once everything is downloaded and configured you will need to delete these files (if not already deleted) from you **JMeter lib directory**:-

**- httpclient-4.2.6.jar**

**- httpcore-4.2.5.jar**

**- httpmime-4.2.6.jar**

Because you will see that every jar file which is mentioned above will be having two versions like `httpmime-4.2.6.jar` and `httpmime-4.5.jar` and you need the latest one only, so while your JMeter is closed, delete these old version of files. After that run your script, it should execute correctly.

For more details refer to the link [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Answer (score 0):

Divya, if you simply want to navigate to "http://google.com", you can simply add a HTTP Request sampler and put the URL in "Server Name or IP" field and it will work as expected. Please let me know if you have any other query regarding this.

Comment: Nishant, adding the "http://google.com" to HTTP Request Sampler will not launch browser,in that case Jmeter will hit this URL in background i.e. without launching browser, which is completely a different scenario and that will not provide the real end user experience.